# Rails nested includes and belongs_to vs. has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am writing an application for a job board. There is a `Users` table where users can post jobs or request to be awarded jobs. Therefore my `Jobs` table has a user_id field for the posting user and a relationship to a `Job_requests` table that has a job_id and a user_id but here the user_id is the requesting user's id.

I am trying to show a job posted by a user:

```
current_user.jobs.find(params[:id])
```

including the requests for that job:

```
current_user.jobs.includes(:job_requests).find(params[:id])
```

but also including the details for the requesting user:

```
current_user.jobs.includes(job_requests: :user).find(params[:id])
```

The first two work but the third crashes with the following error:

```
SQLException (no such column: users.job_request_id)
```

I know there is no such column I am looking for the details of the user that posted the request.

**Model Association**

```
User
has_many :jobs, dependent: :destroy
has_many :job_requests

Job
belongs_to :user
has_many :job_requests

JobRequest
has_one :user
has_one :job
```

Comment: Well.. What is your query ?

Comment: For a job I posted I want to see the requesters with their details

Comment: your schema.rb file please?

Comment: Jobrequest must be belongs_to user and belongs_to job...it should not be has_one

Comment: @Mikael Yes.. do the change as _user123_ said.

Comment: YES!!! that worked. I guess I need to figure out the difference between has_one and belongs_to... user123 you get extra points for being faster than than Arup! not easy...

Comment: Just to provide a little clarity regarding has_one vs belongs_to: if a model holds the foreign key in a relationship it belongs_to the other model. The other model has_on (or has_many) of the first model. For instance, if a User has User_Id and a Job has both Job_Id and User_id, the Job belongs_to the User, and the User either has_one or has_many Jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the following associations:

```
# User

has_many :jobs, dependent: :destroy
has_many :job_requests

# Job

belongs_to :user
has_many :job_requests

# JobRequest

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :job
```

Your query will be:

```
current_user.jobs.includes(job_requests: :user).find(params[:id])
```

---

`belongs_to` & `has_one` :

The only difference is what side of the relationship you are on. If a `User` has a `Profile`, then in the `User` model you need to have `has_one :profile` and in the `Profile` model you need to have `belongs_to :user`.

You can determine who has the other object by looking at where the foreign key is. You can say a `User` has a `Profile` because the `profiles` table has a `user_id` column. If there is a column called `profile_id` on the `users` table, we will say that a `Profile` has a `User`.

For further study you can read this [article](http://duanesbrain.blogspot.com/2006/05/ruby-on-rails-hasone-versus-belongsto.html).

Comment: I think you mean: `job_requests: :user` the way you wrote it I get the posting user. Also, do you mind explaining the difference between has_one and belongs_to to make the answer more complete and solid?

Comment: @Mikael, sure, I am about to update my answer by discussing the difference between `has_one` and `belongs_to`.

Comment: You still have the typo  `:job_request, :user` rather than `job_request: :user`

Comment: @Mikael, when you have direct relation between `Job - JobRequest` and `Job - User`, the include should be like this - `:job_requests, :user`. When there is no direct relation between `Job` and `User`, but through `JobRequest`, the include needs to be like `job_requests: :user`. You got my point?

Comment: @Mikael, does the query raising exception? and unexpected output?

Comment: yea your way I get : `Couldn't find Job with 'id'=300 [WHERE "jobs"."user_id" = ?]`

Comment: Ok, then use yours, I will explain what I got wrong when I come back.

Answer (score 2):

In *job_request.rb* add the following association

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :job_request
```

`belongs_to` is used when you are storing foreign key of a particular model.
When `has_one` is used at that time you are not storing foreign key of another table.

Query should be

`JobRequest.includes (:user, :job).where ('job_requests.job_id  = ? and job_requests.user_id = ? ', params [:id], current_user.id)`

Comment: @mikael check with the query

Comment: My original query works now that I fixed the depencies